# c# удалить разрешения пользователя

Tags: c#, permissions

Нужно на папку программно удалять разрешения определенного пользователя. Нашел пример на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/t1h6d4k4(v=vs.110).aspx). Вот метод оттуда для удаления разрешений:

```
    public static void RemoveDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

        dSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                        Rights,
                                                        ControlType));

        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что он хоть и удаляет разрешения сам пользователь в списке контроля доступом остается. Только без разрешений. А мне нужно удалить его полностью. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот и решение:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectorySecurity Rights = dirInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);
//Только для папок
Rights.RemoveAccessRuleAll(new FileSystemAccessRule(_user.Name,
FileSystemRights.FullControl,
InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,
PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,
AccessControlType.Allow));
//Только для файлов
Rights.RemoveAccessRuleAll(new FileSystemAccessRule(_user.Name,
FileSystemRights.FullControl,
InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,
AccessControlType.Allow));
//Только для этой папки
Rights.RemoveAccessRuleAll(new FileSystemAccessRule(_user.Name,
FileSystemRights.FullControl,
InheritanceFlags.None,
PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,
AccessControlType.Allow));
dirInfo.SetAccessControl(Rights);
```